# Missing Courier font on Terminal macOS Monterey

Tags: terminal, font

I recently got a new laptop, opened up Terminal and noticed that the Courier font is missing entirely!

Is there a way to get this font installed into Terminal?

Thanks!

Comment: AFAIK Courier is available by default. Where did you look for the font?

Comment: @nohillside I went to Preferences, then on the basic profile, clicked "Change" and then scrolled down. You are right that it was available previously, but on the new laptop on Mac OS 12.2, I can't find it anymore :/ As a workaround I've downloaded Courier Prime from google (https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Courier+Prime), but it's not exactly the same.

Comment: There should be a group of fixed width fonts in the Font Picker.

Comment: Also, if you open Font Book (separate application), do you find it there?

Comment: @nohillside This is an example of what I am seeing https://imgur.com/a/qbMkduU. It also seems like other users are experiencing the same https://discussions.apple.com/thread/253481507

Comment: Ah, interesting. I have Courier still in Terminal, but only Courier New in Font Book. And Courier isn't the same as Courier New.

Answer (score 2):

In recent years, Apple seems to have 'hidden' a number of System fonts from font menus, even though they are active. This includes Courier, Athelas, Marion, Iowan Old Style, and others.

Apple describes these fonts as '[Document supported Fonts](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT213266)', which only work in documents that already use them; and are not available in new documents.

You cannot just copy the font to the `/Library` or user `~/Library` font folders: it will still be hidden from font menus.

These are usually .ttc "TrueType Collection" fonts, which contain multiple styles in one file. If you have access to a font editor (such as FontForge, FontLab, Glyphs, etc), you can open the TTC file, and re-save each style as a separate .ttf font file.

These files, when installed, **will** be seen be font menus.

Alternatively, you can install the .dfont file from Catalina or earlier, if you have access to it. Though Apple has been migrating bundled fonts away from the proprietary .dfont format for many years, and may abandon it entirely at some point.

You could download some random version from the internet, but as ever, there's no guarantee of what you're getting.

Answer (score 1):

The Courier conspiracy seems to be getting worse. In macOS Ventura, Courier is no longer available at all in some programs (specifically PyCharm, where it is my current preferred monospaced font).

I made a copy of Courier and changed its internal UUID, and the copy works just fine (just like any other font). So Apple is specifically blocking Courier, for what reason I can only guess.

---

Courier is available in the "PDF" collection.

[image: Fonts dialog box showing the PDF font collection]

The fonts in that collection don't show up in the "English" or "All fonts" collection. You won't find Helvetica or Times in any other collections either.

Thinking that Courier was "disabled," I opened the Font Book application to take a look at the font collections. Inexplicably, Courier doesn't appear in the PDF collection in Font Book, and it didn't show up in a search either. Odd, to say the least.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to install the regular Courier font by downloading the .ttf font file from here:

https://ttfonts.net/font/11165_Courier.htm

and then copying it into my ~/Library/Fonts/ directory. It can be seen in "All Fonts" (not sure how to get it classified as fixed width).